# non-responsive close button in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to make an Option dialog in Visual Studio. I hid the default ControlBox and made a close button. The dialog work, but the close button isn't. Here's the code:

```
    public static class dialog
    {        
        static Form gotoBox = new Form();

        public static void showDialog()
        {
            Button closeButton = new Button() { Text = "Close" };                            

            gotoBox.Controls.Add(closeButton);
            gotoBox.ControlBox = false;
            gotoBox.ShowDialog();

            closeButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(gotoBox_close);               
        }

        static void gotoBox_close(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gotoBox.Close();
        }

    }
```

When I click the button, nothing happen. So what did I do wrong?

Comment: you need to replace 'ShowDialog' by 'Show'. And I believe there are more changes needed in order to be able to run your code more than once. But they are not related to closing your dialog.

Comment: Do what rudolf_franek suggests or assign the event handler prior to ShowDialog()

Comment: Move `closeButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(gotoBox_close);` *before* the ShowDialog line.  It's blocking.  If you call your code multiple times, you are constantly added more buttons on top of each other since you only create the form once.

Comment: Yup.  It is all pretty wrong, you'll add a Click event handler every single time you call showDialog().  And a dialog should be closed by assigning its DialogResult property.  Just don't make it static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gotoBox.ShowDialog(); //This line shows the dialog

//The rest doesn't execute until ShowDialog returns
closeButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(gotoBox_close);
```

You need to move the event registration before the show dialog or else it will not have any effect until dialog is closed